# Decreasing the binding number of an open book while increasing the genus of the pages

Tags: reference-request, contact-geometry

Let $(B,\pi)$ be an open book decomposition of a closed, connected, oriented 3-manifold $M$ with odd (even) binding number and with pages of Euler characteristic $\chi$. Is it possible to define another open book decomposition $(B',\pi')$ of $M$ with binding number one (two) and with pages of the same Euler characteristic $\chi$? Basically, I am trying to replace each pair of boundary components with a genus in pages of $(B,\pi)$ to obtain $(B',\pi')$.

I believe that this is too good to be true, but I have no candidate for a counter-example. However, I think one thing that might work is to pick the contact structure $\xi$ on $M$ compatible with $(B,\pi)$, and looking for $(B',\pi')$ in the collection of all open book decompositions compatible with $\xi$. Maybe if $\xi$ satisfies some certain properties (e.g. tightness), we can detect such a $(B',\pi')$.

Is there any paper that (partially) answers this question or a similar one? Also, is there an obvious counter-example or proof for it (in the general case and in the case where $\xi$ is tight)?

Comment: The smallest instance that I would try are pair-of-pants vs punctured tori. Contact structures supported by the former have been studied by Akiran (Gökova proceedings '07), and the latter have been studied by Baldwin (JTop '08) and Lisca (AGT '14), especially in the case when the 3-manifold is an L-space. My guess is that one can compare the two lists and see that there are some manifolds in the first that don't appear in the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you hope for is not in general possible.

For example, the overtwisted contact structure $\xi_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ on $S^3$ with $d_3 = -\frac{1}{2}$ (*ie.* the overtwisted contact structure in the same homotopy class as $\xi_{\rm{std}}$) has a supporting open book which is a thrice-punctured sphere, by [[Etnyre–Ozbagci, Lemma 5.5]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605441v1.pdf).  If we could replace this open book with one that has a once-punctured torus page, the binding would be a genus-1 fibred knot in $S^3$.  Thus, the binding is either the right-handed trefoil, the left-handed trefoil, or the figure-eight knot, which support $\xi_{\rm{std}}$, $\xi_{\frac{3}{2}}$, and $\xi_{\frac{1}{2}}$, respectively.

Additionally, there is a tight contact structure $\xi$ on $L(3,1)$ supported by $(S_{0,3},\delta_1\delta_2\delta_3)$, where $\delta_i$ are positive Dehn twists about the three boundary components.  If there were an open book decomposition $(S_{1,1}, \phi)$ supporting $\xi$, then the binding is a genus-1 fibred knot in $L(3,1)$.  It's shown in [[Baker]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510391v4.pdf) that $L(3,1)$ admits two equivalence classes of genus-1 fibred knots. Since the bindings of $(S_{1,1}, a^{-3}b^{-1})$ and $(S_{1,1}, a^{-3}b)$ are non-equivalent genus-1 fibred knots in $L(3,1)$, both supporting overtwisted contact structures, it follows that $\xi$ is not supported by a genus-1 open book with one binding component.

Furthermore, we can get similar counter-examples even while ignoring the contact structure.  The open book $(S_{0,3},\delta_1\delta_2\delta_3^5)$ supports $L(11,9)$.  By [[Baker]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510391v4.pdf), this lens space does not have a genus-1 fibred knot, and so is not supported by an open book with genus-1 pages and connected binding.

Comment: Great examples. Thanks @magicker72 ! My primary aim is to reduce the number of binding components (and increase the genus accordingly), whether in the same contact structure or not. I guess your counter-examples tell that the corresponding contact structure may not be useful to do that. Maybe I should try more topological arguments.